# Recursive filter with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to use the Lodash function `_.filter()` to filter an array of array.

I'd like to get only the firsts items that have a score with scaled is equal to `1`.

```js
var newScores = [{name: 'toto', scores: [{score: 10, scaled: 1}, {score: 10, scaled: 0}]}, {name: 'tata', scores: [{score: 500, scaled: 0}, {score: 19, scaled: 0}]}];

var filterScores = _.filter(newScores, function(score) { return _.filter(score.scores, {scaled: 1}); });

console.log(filterScores);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

What I'd like in the result :

```
[{name: 'toto', scores: [{score: 10, scaled: 1}, {score: 10, scaled: 0}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner _.filter you are trying to return  a list - _.filter returns the item that evaluates to a condition so you have to set that condition.

Try adding this *.length > 0;* in the inner filter

```js
var newScores = [{name: 'toto', scores: [{score: 10, scaled: 1}, {score: 10, scaled: 0}]}, {name: 'tata', scores: [{score: 500, scaled: 0}, {score: 19, scaled: 0}]}];

var filterScores = _.filter(newScores, function(score) {
  return _.filter(score.scores, {scaled: 1}).length > 0; // evaluate to a list that is not empty
});

console.log(filterScores);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#some) in the filter callback.

```js
var newScores = [{ name: 'toto', scores: [{ score: 10, scaled: 1 }, { score: 10, scaled: 0 }] }, { name: 'tata', scores: [{ score: 500, scaled: 0 }, { score: 19, scaled: 0 }] }],
    filterScores = _.filter(newScores, ({ scores }) => _.some(scores, { scaled: 1 }));

console.log(filterScores);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need loadash?

```js
var newScores = [{name: 'toto', scores: [{score: 10, scaled: 1}, {score: 10, scaled: 0}]}, {name: 'tata', scores: [{score: 500, scaled: 0}, {score: 19, scaled: 0}]}];

console.log(newScores.filter(val => val.scores[0].scaled === 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper code using lodash would be

```
var newScores = [{name: 'toto', scores: [{score: 10, scaled: 1}, {score: 10, scaled: 0}]}, {name: 'tata', scores: [{score: 500, scaled: 0}, {score: 19, scaled: 0}]}];

var filterScores = _.filter(newScores, function(score) { return score.scores[0].scaled === 1 });

console.log(filterScores);
```